# Полное отсутствие перевода как минимум двух статей из справки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Страница справки, в частности раздел [Наша модель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange), содержит ссылки на две статьи без перевода:

- [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) / Удалили мой вопрос! Что делать?
- [How do I report harassment?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/harassment) / Как реагировать на оскорбления?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Добавил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) перевод «первой» статьи. Вторая будет доступна в ближайшее время.